# Why padding is not as expected in this struct

Tags: padding

```
typedef struct
{
char Data1;
int Data2;
unsigned short Data3;
char Data4;
}SampleStruct;
```

Why do we not have padding bytes(2) after unsigned short Data3 as alignment is that of largest member Data2(4 bytes). So logically structure size should be 13 and not 12 btes with 5 bytes of padding.

Comment: Please add a language tag. Is this Java?

Comment: Please read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] then edit your question.  Padding is dependent on language, compiler, CPU type, bitness (32, 64), possibly OS.